# About the proper use of INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I've been having problems trying to retrieve data from my database to a DataTable in Microsoft Visual C#. I've been told it's because of improper use of INNER JOINs. The query  (Fill method) is the one that follows.

```
SELECT Bordero.id AS id, Titulo.id AS id_titulo, Titulo.valor AS valor_titulo, 
       Sacado.nome AS nome_sacado, Cliente.nome AS nome_cliente, Sacado.documento,
       Titulo.taxa_adm AS taxa_adm_titulo, Titulo.desagio AS desagio_titulo, 
       Titulo.liquido AS liquido_titulo, 
       (CASE Titulo.tipo 
             WHEN 'True' THEN 'Cheque' 
             ELSE 'Duplicata' 
        END) AS tipo, Titulo.dias, Titulo.codigo, Titulo.vencimento, 
       Titulo.data_base, Bordero.desagio AS desagio_bordero, 
       Bordero.taxa_adm AS taxa_adm_bordero, Bordero.liquido AS liquido_bordero, 
       Bordero.bruto, Bordero.duplicata, Bordero.desconto, Bordero.iss, Bordero.iof,
       Bordero.cpmf, Bordero.pis, Bordero.cofins, Desconto.valor AS valor_desconto,
       Desconto.descricao, Bordero.id_cliente
FROM   Bordero 
INNER JOIN Cliente ON Bordero.id_cliente = Cliente.id
INNER JOIN Titulo ON Bordero.id = Titulo.bordero_id
INNER JOIN Sacado ON Sacado.id = Titulo.sacado_id
INNER JOIN Desconto ON Cliente.id = Desconto.id_cliente
```

The database diagram looks like this:
http://i53.tinypic.com/t0g4qp.jpg

Any hints on what's wrong?

Comment: What problem have you been having?  Are you not getting the data you expect, is it throwing exceptions, etc?

Comment: What are the problems? There is nothing wrong with this query as far as the inner joins are concerned. Without knowing what you expect to see and/or what the errors are, it's hard to imagine the problem psychically

Comment: The problem is that the given query returns no data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without stating what your problem is that you're experiencing my guess would be that you may need to be using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for some of the tables instead of all `INNER JOIN`.

When using an `INNER JOIN` in a query, the data that you're matching via the `ON` clause **must** be not null in both tables. Meaning that if the ID exists on the left table (the one in the `FROM` clause) there must be a matching record in the right table (the one you're joining in via the `INNER JOIN`). If the right table does not have a matching record, the entire result is dropped from the query.

By using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead, you allow the right table to return `NULL` instead for each data row that doesn't match.

```
TABLE A       TABLE B
ID  |  Name   ID  | Address
1   |  Alice  1   | 123 ABC St.
2   |  Bob    3   | 789 XYZ St.  
3   |  Cam
```

Using the above tables, if you were to do an `FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID` only rows 1 and 3 would be returned. If you were to do a `FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID` all rows from `A` would be returned and `B.Address` would be null for #2.